# Understanding of Base and dynamic URL in HTTP Request Activity in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to use Azure data Factory to get data from an API call and then use the Copy data activity to push it into a destination. I am trying to use the HTTP request activity as source in my Copy data activity action. My inputs are as follows in the HTTP Request Source:

```
Base URL: https://ABCDEF.com
Relative URL:Parameter
Parameter Passed:@concat('/bulk/v1/activities/export/',variables('Export ID Activities'),'/file.json?client_id=ClientID&client_secret=ClientSecret')
Headers:'Authorization: Bearer ABCDEF'
```

I get the Export ID variable from another call which works without an issue. Even this call works without an issue in Postman. But I get the following error if I try debugging the issue. I think that the issue is with my relative URL. Can relative URL bits and pieces of URL or can it only contain query parameters for an API call?.

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'body('Copy data2ComposeRuntimeVariables')","details":null,"error":null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. You can add more than query parameters to the relative URL. the main request is basically a concatenation of Base URL and Relative URL. When I had parameterized the relative URL, I had named it

> Export ID

pipeline kept failing due to the space in between Export and ID. Removing the space resolved the issue for me and I was able to pass much more stuff to the relative URL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the description of relativeUrl in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http#dataset-properties).

> relativeUrl:  A relative URL to the resource that contains the data. The
> HTTP connector copies data from the combined URL: [URL specified in
> linked service][relative URL specified in dataset].

Based on my test,  relative URL can only contain query parameters. You can hardcode your relative URL to have a try.